# How To Get Value From ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have Code

```
<head>
    <title><%=txtTitle.Text</title>
</head> 

<asp:HiddenField ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />

<asp:ListView ID="lvDetNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsBerita">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFcari" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("judul_berita") %>' />
        <h2><%# Eval("judul_berita") %></a></h2>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

How to get Value HiddenField from Listview?

I'm tring this. But can't display

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField tt = (HiddenField)lvDetNews.FindControl("HFcari");
    txtTitle.Value = "tess" + tt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField tt = (HiddenField)lvDetNews.FindControl("HFcari");
    txtTitle.Value = "tess" + tt.Value;
}
```

**Update:**
You got that error because the listview was not binded yet, so i think the best way would be to do all this on the ItemDataBound event. You would find the hidden field like below:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="lvDetNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsBerita"   OnItemDataBound="lvDetNews_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFcari" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("judul_berita") %>' />
        <h2><%# Eval("judul_berita") %></a></h2>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

protected void lvDetNews_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
         HiddenField tt = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HFcari");
          txtTitle.Value = "tess" + tt.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: pssst, `.Value` property.

Comment: thank you for the answer..
But Same,  This can't display

just Show error message
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

have alternative answer again..

Comment: @user3401322, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField tt = (HiddenField)lvDetNews.FindControl("HFcari");
        txtTitle.Value = "tess" + tt.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value in page load , you should know the row number

```
var hiddenFld = this.lvDetNews.Items[<row_index>].FindControl("HFcari") as HiddenField;
string value = hiddenFld.Value();
```

Otherwise you have to done this in `ItemDataBound` event

```
<head>
    <title><%=txtTitle.Text</title>
</head> 

<asp:HiddenField ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />

<asp:ListView ID="lvDetNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsBerita"   OnItemDataBound="lvDetNews_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFcari" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("judul_berita")     %>' />
        <h2><%# Eval("judul_berita") %></a></h2>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code:

```
protected void lvDetNews_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var hiddenFld = e.Item.FindControl("HFcari") as HiddenFiled;
        string value = hiddenFld.Value();
        // ...
    }
}
```